# User redirection based on role in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancancan, rolify

My requirement is, i have to be able to register as a Super Admin/ admin / Guest and after that, i have to create a sample project as a Super Admin/ admin / Guest.

Super admin have all the permissions like Create,view, edit, delete. Admin have permissions like edit, view and Guest has to have only create access.

But, in my application, Guest is also getting all the permissions like create, update, delete on projects list.

To resolve this problem,

The gems which i used are:

```
gem 'devise'

gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'

gem 'rolify'
```

for redirection based on the role is in **devise / registration / new.html.erb:**

once, i create a new user,(by selecting radio buttons) i was able to save its value 1 (for super admin) / 2 (Admin) / 3(Guest) into the database

**app/models/ability.rb:**

```
class Ability
  include cancan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
     user ||= User.new

    if user.has_role?(:super_admin)
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.has_role?(:admin)
      can :create, Project
      can :update, Project do |project|
        project.ongoing?
      end
      can :read, Project
    elsif user.role?(:guest)
      can :create, Project
    end

  end
end
```

**app/models/role.rb:**

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    resourcify
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles

  belongs_to :resource,
             :polymorphic => true,
  validates :resource_type,
            :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
            :allow_nil => true

  scopify
end
```

**app/models/users.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify :role_cname => 'Usertype'
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy

  def super_admin?
   has_role?(:super_admin)
  end

  def admin?
   has_role?(:admin)
  end

  def guest?
   has_role?(:guest)
  end 
end
```

Comment: Role.rb:
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
 resourcify

Comment: I need some guidance on this, i stucked here since 5 days.

Comment: In **ability.rb**, change `user.role?(:guest)` to `user.has_role?(:guest)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters in your last statement you are calling:

```
elsif user.role?(:guest)
```

whereas in the others you are calling

```
elsif user.has_role?
```

Any questions ask below. Since I am not able to comment yet.

Comment: i had changed user.role?(:guest) to user.has_role?(:guest)....still, no difference.. :(

Comment: It seems as if your roles are not being set properly, because CanCanCan assumes if you don't have access to a model, in your instance Project, it presumably sets access to that model to ( cannot :manage Project). Could you post your code of the application controller?

Comment: class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
 
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    protected

        def configure_permitted_parameters
            devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :usertype) }
            devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :usertype) }
        end
end

Comment: So it seems as if you are missing CanCan's current ability method in the application controller. You will most likely need that. In addition, you will probably want to read this https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions.